# Solution to a radical expression of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Wolfram tells me that the solution to
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{42}\sqrt{(x-6)(x+7)}
+ \sqrt{48}\sqrt{(x-7)(x+7)}
+ \sqrt{56}\sqrt{(x-8)(x+7)}
= 84
\end{equation*}
is $91/11$. May someone offer an algebraic explanation to this?

Comment: $(x-6)(x+7)+(x-8)(x+7)=2(x-7)(x+7)$ is maybe helpful.

Comment: Since $-1267/157$ and $91/11$ are the solutions, the corresponding quadratic is $1727x^2-350x-115297=0$. Hence there might be no elegant way to solve the equation.

Comment: One brute force approach is to subtract $84$ from both sides, then multiply both sides by a rationalizing factor to obtain a polynomial with integer coefficients (only the leading term's coefficient and the constant term need to be explicitly determined), and finally apply the rational root test. For a rationalizing factor (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447543/rationalizing-radicals)), use $(a+b+c+d)(a+b-c+d)(a+b-c-d)$ times $(a-b+c+d)(a-b+c-d)(a-b-c+d)(a-b-c-d),$ where $a^2=42(x-6)(x+7)$ and $b^2=48(x-7)(x+7)$ and $c^2=56(x-8)(x+7)$ and $d=84$ (I think).

Comment: [This 1850 paper by Arthur Cayley](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1850_1_15_A21_0.pdf) might be of help in simplifying some of the algebra (see the rationalized versions on p. 352 of the equation at the bottom of p. 351). Possibly @Michael Hoppe's observations could be of use in the clear-up process for obtaining the leading coefficient and constant term.

Comment: Also, according to the bottom of the first page of [this 1929 paper by Chaundy](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1112/jlms/s1-4.3.171), rationalizing the equation $\sqrt{u+a}+\sqrt{u+b}+\sqrt{u+c}+\sqrt{u+d}=0$ results in an equation linear in $u,$ which along with @Michael Hoppe's second comment, suggests to me that rationalizing *your equation* might lead to a quadratic equation in $x.$ See also the solution to [#169 on pp. 136-137](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VbWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA136) of **Mathematical Gazette** 1 #12 (October 1897).

Comment: See also Article 114 (pp. 246-250) of [this 1835 paper by Wilhelm August Förstemann](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/img/?PID=PPN243919689_0014%7Clog22) and this [1852 paper by Arthur Cayley](https://books.google.com/books?id=6R5bAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA97) (another copy [here](https://archive.org/details/cambridgeanddub01ferrgoog/page/n104)), especially p. 98, on pp. 97-101 of Volume 8 of **Cambridge and Dublin Mathematical Journal**. Where did this equation come from? Surely you didn't just guess it's form.

Comment: One may transform the equation to $$\sqrt{42}\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{24}\sqrt{u+w}+\sqrt{56}\sqrt{w} =84.$$ But how to rationalise this one?

Comment: @Michael Hoppe   Why do you have $\sqrt{24}$?

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro  The article by Chaundy and the solution to the problem posted in the Mathematical Gazette are interesting ... but I am not sure they are relevant to solving the radical expression posted by A Gal named Desire.

Comment: @user143462 It was $\sqrt{48}\sqrt{(u+w)/2}$ before.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro  You say to "multiply both sides by a rationalizing factor to obtain a polynomial with integer coefficients." What is the number?

Comment: It is not a *number* but rather a (very lengthy) algebraic expression --- a polynomial with certain integer coefficients, to be more specific. I described the process in my answer to [Rationalizing radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447543) (see also [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7288329), especially at the end), and I gave a worked out example in this [10 December 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4138179). Also useful is [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778661/is-number-rational/778814#778814).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro  These links discuss sums of integral multiples of radicals. The equation in my post has $\sqrt{42}$, $\sqrt{48}$, and $\sqrt{56}$.

Comment: The terms can be rewritten so that each term is the square root of a non-radical expression. For example, $\sqrt{42}\sqrt{(x-6)(x+7)} = \sqrt{42(x-6)(x+7)}$ and $84 = \sqrt{7056}.$